# Resharper "Run All Tests" is broken

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have just upgrade to VS2013 Update 2 and at the same time I also upgraded resharper to 8.2.0.2160.

Before upgrading I could 'Run All Tests' from the 'Unit Test Sessions" window and all tests worked. All green!

Now I have about 20% of tests failing the most common reason seems to be failing to find 'SomeValue' in the config file. If I run each of these test projects individually (there are about 12 test projects) all tests in the project run fine. All green, all good.

'SomeValue' definitely exists in the config file, if it did not the tests would still fail when running projects individually.

I don't know if it is resharper or VS but I suspect it is resharper. (in case it is relevant most tests are done with NUnit)

Has something changed in the new version? Do I need to tick a configuration box somewhere?

It looks like it uses the config file from the first project that it decides to run??

Any suggestions on how to get this working again?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ticking "Use separate AppDomain for each assembly with tests". This can cause issues with config files - it uses the config file for the first assembly run. It's an optimisation to prevent having to create too many (expensive) AppDomains.

Comment: This setting can be found here (for Visual Studio 2013 with ReSharper 8): RESHARPER > Options > Tools > Unit Testing